Why is the button autoclicked 24 times and become unresponsive when the component starts rendering?
On routes/index.tsx I have:
import Main from "../islands/Counter.tsx";

export default function Home() {
  return (<Main />);
}

On islands/Counter.tsx I have:
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Main() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>click</button>
      {count}
    </main>
  );
}

The first render it shows number 24 and Firefox says "This page is slowing down Firefox". Which part I'm doing wrong?

You're calling setCount, not passing a function which triggers it to your onClick handler (as you should be).
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Main() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  return (
    <main>
-      <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>click</button>
+      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click</button>
      {count}
    </main>
  );
}


why is it different? If we rewrite the arrow function to be an anonymous function function () {return setCount(count + 1)}, I don't see how it be different with just writing setCount(count + 1) at the beginning.

This is a JavaScript fundamental really. setCount() will immediately be called, whereas providing it as part of a callback ensures it'll only trigger when the function is called.

do you have any source elaborating this?

It's important to keep in mind that JSX acts just like normal JS here, in that closures are not automatically created in the output code. I don't have any source beyond the MDN page for functions, as what we're essentially comparing is function Foo() { console.log('foo') } and console.log('foo'). You'd need to invoke the function to trigger the former, but in latter situation, it's ran immediately.
